# Is it practical to delete all heap-allocated memory after you have finished using it?

Tags: c++, c++11, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Are there any specific situations in which it would not be practical nor necessary to delete the heap-allocated memory when you are done using it? Or does not deleting it always affect programs to a large extent?

Comment: Why not leaving it to OS?

Comment: If you allocate and hold until the end of the program you could leave clean-up to the OS. But you'd better leave notes because someone could take your code, wrap it, and assume that it will work as a module inside another program that just inherited an undocumented memory leak.

Comment: If you've ever used certain (very popular) web browsers you'd have felt the pain of being a user to one of these programs where cleaning the heap was considered "optional"

Comment: Not every OS cleans up the mess you leave behind. There are also lots of cases where the destructor of a class is not trivial and does more than just free the memory or close file descriptors. If you don't clean up properly the destructor code isn't run. Examples for this are IPC shared memory resources or client/server architectures.

Answer (score 1):

In a few cases, I've had code that allocated lots of stuff on the heap. A typical run of the program took at least a few hours, and with larger data sets, that could go up to a couple of days or so. When it finished and you exited the program, all the destructors ran, and freed all the memory.

That led to a bit of a problem though. Especially after a long run (which allocated many blocks on the heap) it could take around five minutes for all the destructors to run.

So, I rewrote some destructors to do nothing--not even free memory an object had allocated.

The program had a pretty simple memory usage pattern, so everything it allocated remained in use until you shut it down. Disabling the destructors so they no longer released the memory that had been allocated reduced the time to shut down the program from ~5 minutes to what appeared instant (but was still actually pretty close to 100 ms).

That said, this is really only rarely an option. The vast majority of the time, a program should clean up after itself. With well written code it's usually pretty trivial anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any specific situations in which it would not be practical
>   nor necessary to delete the heap-allocated memory when you are done
>   using it?

Yes.

---

In certain types of telecomm embedded systems I have seen:

1) an operator commanded software-revision-update can also perform (or remind the user to perform) a software reset as the last step in the upgrade.  This is not a power bounce, and (typically) the associated hw continues to run.

Note:  There are two (or more) kinds of revision updates: 1) processor code;  and 2) firmware (of the fpga's which is typically stored in eprom)

In this case, there need not be a delete of long-term heap allocated memory.  The embedded software I am familiar with has many new'd data structures that last the life of the code.  Software reset is the user-commanded end-of-life, and the memory is zero'd at system startup (not shutdown).  No dtor's are used at this point, either.

There is often a customer requirement about the upper limit on how long a system reboot takes.  The time starts when the customer wants ... perhaps at the start of the download of a new revision ... so a fast reset can help achieve that additional requirement.

---

2) I have worked on (embedded telecom) systems with a 'Watchdog' feature to detect certain inconsistencies (including thread 'hangs').  This failure mechanism generates a log entry in some persistent store (such as battery-back-static-ram or eprom or file system).

The log entry is evidence of some 'self-detected' inconsistency.

Any attempt to delete heap memory would be suspect, as the inconsistency might have already corrupted the system.  This reset is not user-commanded, but may have site policy based controls.  A fast reset is also desired here to restore functionality when the reset occurs with no user at the console.

---

Note:

IMHO, The most useful "development features" for embedded system (none of which trigger heap clean up efforts) are :

a) a soft-reset switch (fairly common availability) - reboots the processor with no impact to the hw that the software controls/monitors.  Is used often.

b) a hard-reset switch (availability rare) - power bounces the card .. both processor and the equipment it controls, without impact to the rest of the cards in the shelf.  (Unknown utility.)

c) a shelf-reset switch (some times the shelf has its own switch) - power bounces the shelf and all cards, processors and equipment within.  This is seldom used, (except for system startup issues) but the alternative is to clumsily 'pull the power plug'.

d) computer control of these three switches - I've never seen it.

Comment: "memory is zero'd at system startup (not shutdown)" - so any reset of the processor will not need delete of heap-allocated-memory.  Clearly, this is not a desktop.  My experience is mostly vxWorks.  See boot sequence and bsp notes.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any specific situations in which it would not be practical
>   nor necessary to delete the heap-allocated memory when you are done
>   using it?

Any heap memory you allocate and never free will remain allocated until your process exits.  During that time, no other program will be able to use that portion of the computer's RAM for any purpose.

So the question is, will that cause a problem?  The answer will depend on a number of variables:

1. How much RAM has your process allocated?
2. How much RAM does the computer have physically installed and available for other programs to use?
3. How long will your process continue running (and thus holding on to that memory) for?

If your program is of the type that runs, does its thing, and then exits (more-or-less) immediately, then there's likely no problem with it "leaking" memory, since the leaked memory will be reclaimed by the OS when your process exits (note:  some very primitive/embedded/old OS's may not reclaim the resources of an exited process, so make sure your OS does -- that said, almost all commonly in-use modern OS's do)

If your program is of the type that can continue running indefinitely, on the other hand, then memory leaks are going to be a problem, because if the program keeps allocating memory and never freeing it, eventually it will eat up all of the computer's available RAM and then bad things will start to happen.

In general, there is no reason why you should ever have to leak memory in a modern C++ program -- smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr`) are there specifically to make memory-leaks easy to avoid, and they are easier to use than the old/leak-prone raw C pointers, so there's no reason not to use them.